# Can a locked file be moved in macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, file

I have a file which I've locked since I've accidentally changed it a few times when I meant to just use it unchanged for reference.  I'd like to move it to a different folder (ideally using the Finder).  I know that I can do this by unlocking the file in the Finder's "Get Info" window for the file, moving the file, then re-locking it.  Is there any way to do this as a single step without unlocking it in the middle?

I attempted the same operation using the `mv` command in Terminal, and that failed with an "Operation not permitted" error.

I am using macOS Ventura.

Comment: What file are you trying to move? A system file? a read-only file?

Comment: @RishonJR Just a regular document I created in the past that I want to use for reference, but which I'd rather prefer not changing on accident while doing so.

Answer (score 2):

You could just set it as a Stationery Pad instead, then you could do anything with it except overwrite it. Apps will always open a copy.

[image]

The only downside I can see is that you wouldn't get the warning if you tried to delete it.

Comment: You could alleviate the downside by entering a command to add a ACL. For example after entering `chmod +a "everyone deny delete" "TV 2020.rtf"`, a popup asking for a password would be generated when using the Finder to "Move to Trash".

Comment: Correct me if I'm misremembering, but I think I remember that being an option since the Classic Mac OS days.  I don't think I've ever really had cause to use it before, so it's truly something my eyes just skip over.

Comment: I honestly don't remember when it appeared, but yes, long, looong time ago. I can't say it's something I've ever used a lot, but it's there if you need it :)

Comment: @Tetsujin My foggy memory is telling me I saw it on my System 7 Mac back in the early '90s.  I think it changed the shape of the document icon in the Finder as well.

Comment: Too long ago to remember. My first Mac ran System 6.0.6 but I don't recall really how anything worked back then.

Answer (score 1):

One of the purposes of locking a file is to prevent the file from being moved. To prevent an unlocked file from being changed, set the privileges to "Read only" as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Warning: setting the file permissions to readonly will not keep it from being deleted. Some programs will "edit" files by deleting and replacing them, and readonly permission does not fully prevent this (although many programs that do this are, shall we say, polite enough to refuse to edit readonly files).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: A program would have to actually contain code to deliberately overcome the "Read only" privilege. Such a program could also just as easily contain  code to deliberately overcome the "Locked" status. Neither requires a password to remove or bypass. Both require the cooperation of the installed software.